# Monitor drives status on Dell servers from Linux without OMSA

Tags: monitoring, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have some servers where, for various reasons, I cannot install the Dell OMSA toolset.

Usually, I have hardware RAID configured for the disks (PERC). Also, most of my servers have an iDRAC configured (out-of-band management).

Is there a way to **check the status (faulty, predicitve failure, healthy) of my servers' disks?** I tried IPMI on one machine but it doesn't seem to give that information.

It should work within a script because the final goal is integration within Zabbix.

Comment: Can you outline your reasons a little bit?

Comment: iDrac 7 & 8 support out-of-band disk monitoring. So you may `ssh` into idrac and use `racadm` to check disk health.

Answer (score 1):

If your restriction is with installing any software, you are out of luck. If you just can't install 3rd party software, there's `MegaCli`. (Typically available with your operating system media/update repositories.) Dell has [provided documentation](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN283135/EN).

You will likely need to parse and format the output to get the desired information ready for Zabbix.